Postfix doesn't start with systemctl but with "postfix start" does
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, "postfix start" and "postfix stop" work like a charm.
systemctl start postfix
(no answer)
/var/log/syslog
2024-12-13T21:49:14.744589+01:00 aaa systemd[1]: Starting postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
2024-12-13T21:49:15.002726+01:00 aaa systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-12-13T21:49:15.003169+01:00 aaa systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-12-13T21:49:15.004922+01:00 aaa systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).

journalctl -xeu postfix@-.service
This looks like spam.

systemctl status postfix.service
systemctl status postfix.service
postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2024-12-13 20:51:32 CET; 1h 1min ago
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 960 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 960 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 7ms

Dec 13 20:51:31 aaa systemd[1]: Starting postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Dec 13 20:51:32 aaa systemd[1]: Finished postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent.

systemctl status postfix@-.service
postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix@.service; enabled-runtime; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-12-13 21:49:15 CET; 4min 48s ago
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 2191 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh - (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 246ms

Dec 13 21:49:14 aaa systemd[1]: Starting postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Dec 13 21:49:15 aaa systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 13 21:49:15 aaa systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 13 21:49:15 aaa systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).

postfix check
(no answer) = configuration ok
Tried everything without the files
/var/lib/postfix/master.lock
/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid

I tried also
inet_interfaces = ipv4
and
#inet_interfaces = ipv4
Nothing changes.
Help, thank you

I found the solution!
systemctl start postfix
executes
/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh
and the script was returning 1 (error) because there was a wrong
/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem.
I get it from
/var/spool/postfix/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
and now everything works.
P.S.
And /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem had been overwritten because I had created a new /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem file without realize that /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem was a link to /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem, overwriting it

Do not use the snakeoil.pem but get a real certificate.
